# TYPO3 content row wrap

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In typoscript I can wrap a column when it has content using something like this:

```
styles.content.getMyColumn < styles.content.get
styles.content.getMyColumn.select.where = colPos = 0     
styles.content.getMyColumn.stdWrap {
  wrap = <div>|</div>
  required = 1
}
```

I want to do a similar thing but instead wrap the whole row the column is in. Does anyone know how to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is depending on your TypoScript/Template setup.

A way to do it in TS is:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    # Row 1
    10 = COA
    10 {
        # Column 1
        10 < styles.content.get
        10.select.where = colPos = 0 
        10.wrap = <div class="row1-column1">|</div>

        # Column 2
        20 < styles.content.get
        20.select.where = colPos = 2 
        20.wrap = <div class="row1-column2">|</div>

        # Wrap the row
        wrap = <div class="row1">|</div>
    }
}
```

A better approach is to use `FLUIDTEMPLATE` for the whole page and separate the markup from the TypoScript. This makes it more readable because the whole HTML markup is in your HTML template file.

Comment: This is for an existing site that is using a non-fluid setup. Currently it uses: `page.10 = template` how would I use your COA example without overriding the template file?

Comment: Is it using subparts? You could define the whole row as a subpart and add the COA to it.

Comment: Oh I understand. Then to make it work I used `stdWrap.required = 1` and `stdWrap.wrap = <div>|</div>` to wrap the row only when there is content. Thanks.